# Navbar links to a subfolder

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Whenever I have a link to a page in a sub-folder it freezes the Navbar in the sub-folder so that the browser links stay in the sub-folder and cant' be found. In Visual Studio Express using Master pages. Master page looks like this:

```
  <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="StyleSection" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Subfolder/About.aspx">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Subfolder/contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="action.aspx">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="action2.aspx">Action 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Subfolder/SomethingElse.aspx">Something else</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentSection" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="scriptsection" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Navbar loads fine but after clicking, say "Contact," the Dropdown doesn't dropdown nor do any other links from the navbar work. It doesn't want to get out of the Subfolder.

```
http://localhost:49679/Subfolder/contact.aspx#
```

I doesn't matter whether I'm in IIS Express from VS or after publishing to my local server:

```
http://192.168.1.67/navtest/Subfolder/contact.aspx#
```

I've re-coded one section of my website successfully but I had to put all the .aspx pages in the root of the folder. I can't do that with the rest of the website. The html is from a test project in VS. I've tried adding "~"s and changed paths all over the place but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

The paths to your CSS fils and JS files will be incorrect when viewing a sub-page.

`href="Content/bootstrap.css"` - your browser will try to load `bootstrap.css` from a folder called `Content` that is at the *same level* as the current page. This will work for your root page but not for sub-pages.

`href="/Content/bootstrap.css"` adding a leading `/` will start at the root folder and so should work on any page throughout your site no matter what level the current page is found.

You will find that your links will also not work due to the same reason.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I'd tried everything but adding the leading "/" to all the scripts and links has solved the problem. I knew it was simple.

Comment: ive always wanted to know what that "/" meant, thank you